# Liferay 7: how to reference user class from many to many in custom portlet

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, spring-data, liferay-7

i'm developing a custom portlet in liferay 7 ga3.

I'm using spring data jpa in may data layer, i have my own database and my own connection, my own entities are annotated.

In one of my entity class i need a many to many relationship with the Liferay's User class (com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User),

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "authuserservice", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "servicename"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "screenName"))
List<User> users;
```

but i'm gettin the error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: it.realt.trasparenza.services.services.Service.users[com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1223)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:800)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
```

does anyone know how can i solve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The exception is clear. You are using your own hibernate configuration instead of using liferay service builder. This happens because your entities in hibernate does not include User.class mapping.

In other words, use service builder model entities to work in liferay in the way you want or you will only be able to work with your custom hibernate entities.

You could also "hack" this problem if you implement a View SQL mapped in your hibernate configuration that points to User Table, and you define your list object to View entity. But I do not recommend it.